# Is restriction of $C^{\infty}$ map to a subspace differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open set. Let $f \in C^{\infty}(U)$. Let $S$ be a vector subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with subspace topology. Let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ on $S \cap U$, i.e., $g = f|_{S \cap U}$. $g$ is certainly continuous. I am wondering whether it makes sense to talk about differentiability of $g$ if considered as a function over $S \cap U$ and the ambient space as $S$. In this way, $S \cap U$ is open in $S$ and it seems $g$ would as well be $C^{\infty}$. But this does not feel completely right.

Comment: why does this not feel right?

Comment: (suggestion: start with differentiable instead of infinitely often continuously differentiable and write down the definition. Then investigate continuity and start an induction)

Comment: (Alternative suggestion: recall the relation between continuous differentiabllity and partial derivatives. Then choose a coordinate system of the ambient space which is adapted to the subspace $S$, i.e. such that the first $k$, say, coordinates span $S$).

Comment: You can define the directional derivative of $f:S\subseteq \Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^k$ along $S$ at $p\in S$ as the linear map $\partial_Sf(p):S\to \Bbb R^k$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0, h, p+h\in S} \frac{f(p+h)-f(p)-\partial_Sf(p)(h)}{\|h\|}=0, $$if it exists. For $S = \Bbb R v$ with $\|v\|=1$ we recover $\partial f/\partial v$.